# Icecast disconnects from Ices source client after couple of days

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, icecast

I have set up Icecast 2.3.3 server on Fedora 32, I use Ice04 as a mp3 streaming client. Everything works fine for some time, generally a few days. After that time, Icecast disconnects from Ices with this message in the error.log

```
[2021-04-02  14:21:32] DBUG source/get_next_buffer last 1617366081, timeout 10, now 1617366092
[2021-04-02  14:21:32] WARN source/get_next_buffer Disconnecting source due to socket timeout
[2021-04-02  14:21:32] INFO source/source_shutdown Source "/channel2" exiting
[2021-04-02  14:21:32] DBUG source/source_clear_source clearing source "/channel2"
```

From google search, I found that this problem happened with others also. From what I understood the reason it disconnects is that the streaming client did not send any data within a given time period. A recommended solution was setting up the `source-timeout` to higher number. So I did update my Icecast confing and here is how it looks now in the limits section

```
       <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
       <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
       <header-timeout>60</header-timeout>
       <source-timeout>60</source-timeout>
       <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
       <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
```

I changed it from 10, to 60. But the problem still persists. It still disconnects after few days, with the same message. `Disconnecting source due to socket timeout`.

I don't really understand why this happens.

Why Ices does not send any data for 60 seconds?

I tried to find a solution on the web, reading through forums and it seems like others also encountered this problem but nowhere I really found some reasonable answer. All the discussions basically end up nowhere. For some it miraculously started working well, others probably gave up.

So, I am really confused about what is happening there, how to troubleshoot it and fix it.

Could anyone bring some more light to this issue?

Comment: This could happen if the source is loosing connection due to networking issues. In 90% it is the case, but only if you have Icecast and Ices on different servers. Another option is to check source client logs (not Icecast) cause if source is loosing connection - it knows better why, try enabling highest debugging level.

Comment: i use ices0.4 as generator on the same server. ices does not log anything about it disconnected

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I did actually - the reason why it disconnected in my case was that i had some mp3 files with errors. So i removed them  and now it works ok